# javascript loop on object with just one array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

i've this structure of object which I need to loop on and find some value on the array ,e.g. find if user name is eq to `user2` , I was able to do it with two object ( create another object and put there the array key like users, address etc ) but I want to know If I can do it with only on object,

This is sample of the object

```
var stuff = {
users :['user1','user2'],
address:['addr1', 'addr2'],
emails:['email1', 'email2'],
};
```

Comment: I'm having a very hard time understanding your question, particularly the _"create another object and put there the array key like users, address etc"_ part. Can you give an example (with code) of what you are able to do and a more thorough description of what you are trying to do here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var stuff = {
users :['user1','user2'],
address:['addr1', 'addr2'],
emails:['email1', 'email2'],
}
console.log(Object.keys(stuff))
```

output will be

```
["users", "address", "emails"]
```

Iterate though content
assuming that you want find `user2` in all keys of object.

```
keys = Object.keys(stuff)
for(let i in keys){
    // do something
    //console.log(stuff[keys[i]])
    ind = stuff[keys[i]].indexOf('user2')
    if(ind >=0){
        console.log('user2 found in ', keys[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer but it's not working :) I got undfiend in the loop

Comment: that is obvious. because within loop body there is no code. you should search for element. insode

Comment: @Ninawatcher check this out. I hope this is what you need

Answer (score 0):

```
var stuff = {
    users :['user1','user2'],
    address:['addr1', 'addr2'],
    emails:['email1', 'email2'],
};

function check(a) {
  for(var key in stuff) {
    var arr = stuff[key];
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            return arr[i] == a;
    }
  }
}

alert(check("user2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the [Array#indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) of `user2` in `stuff.users` is not -1:

```js
var stuff = {
  users: ['user1', 'user2'],
  address: ['addr1', 'addr2'],
  emails: ['email1', 'email2'],
};

var isUser2Included = stuff.users.indexOf('user2') !== -1;

console.log(isUser2Included);
```

Answer (score -1):

Or so:

```js
var stuff = {
  users: ['user1', 'user2'],
  address: ['addr1', 'addr2'],
  emails: ['email1', 'email2'],
};

stuff.findIt = (key, val) => stuff[key].indexOf(val) != -1;

console.log(stuff.findIt('users', 'user1'));
console.log(stuff.findIt('users', 'user3'));
console.log(stuff.findIt('emails', 'email1'));
```

Comment: Finding an item in an object by attaching a new method to it? Not a very good idea. What if it already has a `find` property that you're overwriting?

Comment: @JLRishe Well, you are saying that overwriting is a bad habbit? :)))) I get your concern but ...

Comment: @JLRishe but, to be more catholic than Pope, I rename the method. You can up vote it niw :))